maximum of random matrix
Let $(M_{k,n})_{\substack{0\leqslant k\leqslant K\\ 0\leqslant n \leqslant N}}$ a matrix of nonnegative random variables and let $C$ be a constant. Assume that for all $0\leqslant n\leqslant N$, $\mathbb{E}\big[\max_{0\leqslant k\leqslant K} M_{k,n} \big] \leqslant C$  and for all $0\leqslant k\leqslant K$, $\mathbb{E}\big[\max_{0\leqslant n\leqslant N} M_{k,n} \big] \leqslant C$.
I'm trying to prove (or disprove ) this $\mathbb{E}\big[\max_{\substack{0\leqslant n\leqslant N\\ 0\leqslant k\leqslant K}} M_{k,n} \big] \leqslant C$ ?
Any hints would be appreciated.

It cannot be hold. Let $K=1$, and $M_{0,n}, M_{1,n}\sim \mathcal U (0,1), n=0,\dots,N$, for which we have $C=\frac{N}{N+1}$. However, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{\substack{0\leqslant n\leqslant N\\ 0\leqslant k\leqslant K}} M_{k,n} \right] =\frac {2N}{2N+1}>C$$
considering that the distribution of the maximum of $m$ iid random variables with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ follows $\text{Beta}(m,1).$

The OP probably meant to specify that $K>0$

I don't understand your conterexample, in this case $\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{\substack{0\leqslant n\leqslant N\ 0\leqslant k\leqslant K}} M_{k,n} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{\substack{0\leqslant n\leqslant N}} M_{0,n} \right] $ by taking $C=\frac{N}{N+1}$, my clam still holds

Could you check the updated example, in which both row and column expectations are less than $\frac{N}{N+1}$, but the matrix expectation is $\frac{2N}{2N+1}$, larger than $\frac{N}{N+1}$?

Yes i see, thank you very much
